# Django: Can't get models fields to show in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I can't get the cat name and kitten type from the Cat and Kitten models into the template.

This is my model.py

```
class Cat(models.Model):
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cat_name

class Kitten(models.Model):
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Cat, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='kittens')
    kitten_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.kitten_type
```

My views.py

```
class CatViews(generic.ListView):
    model = Cat
    template_name = 'polls/cats.html'


class CatDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Kitten
    template_name = 'polls/kitten.html'
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('cats/', views.CatViews.as_view(), name='catlist'),
    path('cats/<int:pk>/', views.CatDetail.as_view(), name='catdetail'),
]
```

And finally, polls/kitten.html

```
<h3>{{cat.cat_name}}</h3>

{% for kitty in cat.kittens.all %}
    <p>{{ kitty.kitten_type }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

The url is working, I'm just not able to display the fields from the models into their respective html elements. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I had to set the CatDetailView to the Cat model, not Kitten model.

The final code:

```
class CatDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Cat
    template_name = 'polls/kitten.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class CatViews(generic.ListView):
    model = Cat
    template_name = 'polls/cats.html'
    context_object_name='cat'
```

And your polls/cats.html would be like,

```
<h3>{{cat.cat_name}}</h3>

{% for kitty in cat.kittens.all %}
<p>{{ kitty.kitten_type }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alter you `views.py` with the following

```
class CatViews(generic.ListView):
    model = Cat
    context_object_name = 'cat'
    template_name = 'polls/cats.html'
```

Alter your `polls/kitten.html`

```
<h3>{{cat.cat_name}}</h3>

{% for kitty in cat.kittens.all %}
    <p>{{ kitty.kitten_type }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT**

Additionally, alter you `CatDetail`

```
class CatDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Kitten
    context_object_name = 'kittens'
    template_name = 'polls/kitten.html'
```

**EDIT 2**

Alter your `polls/kitten.html` to this.

```
<h3>{{cat.cat_name}}</h3>

{% for kitty in cat.catdetail.all %}
    <p>{{ kitty.kitten_type }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. I can't for the life of me figure out why it isn't.